# Sort 2 views in a page by 2 different ways

Tags: views

I have a simple view, i create a page and a block for view and place them in a page, but How can I sort them in different way:

View Page (sort with nid : asc)
- View Block (sort with nid : desc)
- How can I do this with php field (use with Views_PHP)

Have a nice day
THanks.

Comment: click override button in nid field on both page and block and then change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following steps:-

1.go to your page view: and then click on "sort with nid : asc" or whatever selection criteria.
2. Then it will open a pop-up, so look at the top left most part, there will be a select box, select display overide thing.

Repeat same thing for block view

:)

Comment: Hi thank so muck, I think hook_views_query_alter can help we do that thank

Comment: You can do a lot more things with hook_views_query_alter()
:)

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I understand,

1. You have created a 'page view' and a 'block view'.
2. Now you want those to be sorted in two different ways.

Well, that's straight forward. But I got a confusion with your statement '..and place them in a page..'. Do you want to mean that you shall place your 'page view' and 'block view' in a another page? If so, then it's not the right approach, as you already have a 'page view' which will have it's own URL or, MENU.

Now, considering the feasible scinario where you want to display 'block view' in the 'page view' where both will have same content but in different sort orders, that you can just manage from drupal view's sort criteria.

Hope it helps